# Find a process on linux sending a request to a specific port

Tags: linux, networking

We have a process running on a box listening to specific port 9001. We are trying to identify another process running on the same box which might be sending request to this process on the given port.

We do have a TCP dump for the given port (9001) , but it shows ports which are sending request to this port(9001) but are short lived before we can catch it.

Is there any other way available to catch this process ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use netstat -anp in Linux on port 9001 to see which process send a sync request to this port.

Comment: Thanks , it was helpful.